# How many cores in my cpu?

Tags: cpu

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1840 @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x19
cpu MHz     : 1105.200
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5600.46
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G1840 @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x19
cpu MHz     : 1098.364
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5601.39
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

There are two processor for my cpu,processor0 and processor1.
processor0 contains two cpu cores,procesor1 contains two cpu cores also.
Does it mean that there are four cpu cores in my cpu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cores in your cpu. But to operating system, it may appear as 4 cores due to hyperthreading (if your cpu supports).

https://www.howtogeek.com/194756/cpu-basics-multiple-cpus-cores-and-hyper-threading-explained/

Answer (score 3):

Your processor contains 2 cores. Most of the information, including core count, from /proc/cpuinfo is about the entire processor, not each core.

https://ark.intel.com/products/80800/Intel-Celeron-Processor-G1840-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz

Comment: Most of the information, including core count, from /proc/cpuinfo is about the entire processor, not each processor.

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/products/80800/Intel-Celeron-Processor-G1840-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz

Comment: The core id field is the key which core this cpu entry refers to. Most fields refer to the whole cpu. This is a leftover from the old days where typically a cpu only had 1 core.